# How can I display images stored in a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have some jpg images in MySQL table. How can I display these images?

Could someone please help me by providing sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
$image = $row['myimage']; 
header("Content-type: image/gif");
print $image; 
exit; 
>?
```

But it seems easier just to store the path...

Comment: it show these codes for me  



��C  

���T"�� 
���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�

Comment: What type of image are u storing? You need to replace GIF with the appropriate type.

Comment: i stored jpeg files in my table

Answer (score 0):

The concept is somewhat similar to the below code where `img1.jpg` is an image file

```
$handle = fopen('img1.jpg', 'r');

header("Content-type: image/gif");//make sure that you dont have output before it

echo fread($handle, filesize('img1.jpg'));
```

And try for next experiment

```
$handle = fopen('img1.jpg', 'r');

echo fread($handle, filesize('img1.jpg'));
//If you are storing the output of this in
//your db then this should work
//however it is best recommended to store 
//path which makes you jog a lot easir

//if you get the same error then you have error in 
//storing your file
```